# Validate email for match in XML using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Struggling with this one, i am a student, please help point me in the right direction.

I have the following javascript code to check the XML document for a matching email, alert the user and return false.

```
function validateEmail() 
{
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
     {
         if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
         {
           checkEmail(xhttp);
         }
     }
     xhttp.open("GET", "customer.xml", true);
     xhttp.send();

     function checkEmail(xml) 
     {
         var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
         x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("email");
         txt = "";
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
        { 
           txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
        if (document.myForm.email.value == txt ) 
           {
              alert('That email is taken');
              document.myForm.phone.focus();
              return false;
           }
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = txt;

     }
}
```

Can i get recommendations. It outputs the emails in the XML file so that is working but the if statement doesnt seem to work quite right. ??

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customers>
 <customer>
    <customerid>
        1
    </customerid>
    <firstname>
        ben
    </firstname>
    <surname>
        ben
    </surname>
    <email>
        ben@gmail.com
    </email>
    <password>
        ben
    </password>
    <phone>
    </phone>
</customer>
</customers>
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Registration</h1>
<p>New Users please enter your details below:</p>
<div id="test">TEST</div>
<fieldset>
        <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" >
            <legend>
                Email: <input type='email' name='email' onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value='Your email'}" onfocus="{validateEmail()} if (this.value == 'Your email') {this.value=''}"/>
                <br><br>
                First Name: <input type='text' name='firstname'/>
                <br><br>
                Last Name: <input type='text' name='lastname'/>
                <br><br>
                Password: <input type='password' name='password'/>
                <br><br>
                Re-Type Password: <input type='password' name='password1'/> 
                <br><br>
                Phone Number:<input type='tel' name='phone'/>
                <span>* Optional </span>
                <br><br>
                <input type='Submit' value='Register' />
                <input type='Reset' value='Reset'/>
            </legend>
        </form>
</fieldset>
<br><br>
<a href='home.htm'>Home</a></p>
```

Comment: please show us the content of the xml

Comment: are "myForm" and "email" the names of the form and form input? cha you post your form html as well

Comment: Added  the html above :)

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating the existing email addresses to the string `txt`.

You should use an array to keep track of the email addresses, and check if the input value is in the array.

```
function checkEmail(xml) {
    var x = xml.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("email"),
         arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
       arr.push(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }
    if (arr.indexOf(document.myForm.email.value) > -1) {
        alert('That email is taken');
        document.myForm.phone.focus();
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: It wont work, shows no error message when i enter ben@gmail.com. ?

Comment: try to trim the addresses in the xml and value in the form

Comment: for what I understood he actually has a single email for now, so the concatenations actually is a single email, yet it does not work...

Comment: What do you mean trim the address is XML and what do i do to which value in the form? Sorry.